# WooCommerce Populate Cart Through 3rd Party App

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm very new to WooCommerce but I work with JavaScript/React. I am trying to use them as a back end and create my own front end store front. I pull all of my data from WC to display on my store front. Once a user adds items to my cart on my store front, I want them to be able to checkout via WC so that I don't have to handle payment. Is there a way to populate the cart / checkout with a query string?

Comment: Carts belong to a user. Is your user logged in to WordPress in your frontend?

Comment: @user8262086 no but they don't seem to need to be signed in. I'm looking at another store front hosted on wc/wp and I can add to a cart without being signed in

Comment: You are correct if the buyer is not logged WooCommerce generates a one time only customer id like '702f1d6d3cf1dcbe52aa3aaa1977d1c3' and binds the cart to that customer id. It just may make it a little more difficult to get a handle to the cart but nothing a little coding can't solve.

Comment: @user8262086 I see that using the API, http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs, I can create a new user. Not sure if I can just pass an empty object to that function because I don't want to add in any details just create a custom id so the cart has something to reference. My biggest problem is that I don't see anything that has to do with adding items to the cart.

Comment: I don't think you need to create a user. Once, WooCommerce has generated the one time only customer id it sends to the client as a cookie. Thereafter, WooCommerce uses the cookie to get the correct cart for the customer. So, my comment about getting a handle to the cart I think is incorrect. WooCommerce will get the right handle for the cart using the cookie. It is only a problem if you wish to manipulate the cart outside of the normal WooCommerce process then you need the customer id to get the right cart. I don't think you need to manipulate the cart outside of the normal WooCommerce process

Comment: @user8262086 so on my third party app how do I allow a user to add items to a WC cart? I'm using JavaScript and it seems like their function is in PHP (https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart.html#956-963)

Comment: The WooCommerce frontend client is in a browser running JavaScript. It sends a HTTP request to populate the WooCommerce cart. You can just send a your own HTTP request to populate the cart. I believe on receipt of the request WooCommerce would generate a one time only customer id and bind the cart to that id.

Comment: @user8262086 it seems like they only have a Node client, not a front end client for JS. Can you link it if so?

Comment: WooCommerce has a front end client that runs in a browser that uses JavaScript. The normal WooCommerce distribution does not use Node (as far as I know). There are some client libraries for accessing the WooCommerce REST API using different languages. There may be such a Node library, I don't know. You don't need the REST API to populate the cart. I am not even sure if the REST API has an endpoint for manipulating the cart. It does have an endpoint for manipulating orders and maybe you can work with that.

Comment: @user8262086 I just found a query that will work for redirecting the user from my page and to the cart page of WC site:

https://your_woocommerce_site.com/cart/?add-to-cart=product_id&quantity=1

Now I just need a way to send my key and secret to WC from my react front end to get my products

Comment: That URL will add the product to the cart. Are you trying to use the REST API to access the cart?

Comment: @user8262086 no, I will always assume that when they come to my React app they will have a fresh cart. Once they add items on my React app cart I will use that query to send them to the WC site for checkout/payment processing. Do you know of a front end JS sdk for WC? All I see is the node SDK. I need to pass my token and secret to WC to get the data

Comment: I would use the backbone client that WordPress provides.

Comment: @user8262086 looking at it now, I don't see where I would get data from my WC store though

(https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/)

Comment: That library works with the standard WordPress REST endpoints it has to be extended to support the WooCommerce REST endpoints. Depending on what you are trying to do it may be easier create the REST requests from scratch.

Comment: @user8262086 I just want to get all the products from the WC store

Comment: There may be a significant security risk in using the REST API from the buyer's web page. If credentials are required and the buyer is not logged in you would be forced to use the shop owner's key and secret. This would expose the shop owner's credentials to the buyer. It may not be a problem with products but certainly accessing a buyer's own orders would require credentials. That may be one reason all current WooCommerce REST API client libraries are for server side use.

Comment: @user8262086 ah ok thanks that makes a lot of sense. I guess even read only access is still a bit risky